# Baggage Propagation in Jms using Spring Cloud Sleuth

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-jms, spring-cloud-sleuth

I'm trying to use the baggage propagation offered by Spring Cloud Sleuth. In the calls that use the Feign client I don't have any kind of problem, I can propagate custom fields, while while using JmsTemplate of Spring JMS I can't propagate the same fields.

My application is a Spring Boot application, version 2.1.5, with Spring Cloud version Greenwich.SR1.

In order to put the custom fields, I use

```java
ExtraFieldPropagation.set("communicationId", "123456");
```

while, inside my application.properties, I put

```java
spring.sleuth.baggage-keys= communicationId
```

I expect that the same functionality present for the Feign client, is also present for the producer JMS. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Please ensure that there's no whitespace between the `=` and the `communicationId`. Also please ensure that you're using the latest available versions

Comment: I try updating to the latest version (Greenwich.SR2) and removing whitespace, but the problem persists.

Comment: Ok can you create an issue and upload a sample?

Comment: Documentation states that baggage is not propagate do JMS, see https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/reference/html/#spring-jms